# Create CImage from Byte array

Tags: c++, mfc, atl

I need to create a [CImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwea7by5%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) from a byte array (actually, its an array of `unsigned char`, but I can cast to whatever form is necessary). The byte array is in the form "RGBRGBRGB...". The new image needs to contain a **copy** of the image bytes, rather than using the memory of the byte array itself.

I have tried many different ways of achieving this -- including going through various HBITMAP creation functions, trying to use BitBlt -- and nothing so far has worked.

To test whether the function works, it should pass this test:

```
BYTE* imgBits;
int width;
int height;
int Bpp;   // BYTES per pixel (e.g. 3)
getImage(&imgBits, &width, &height, &Bpp); // get the image bits

// This is the magic function I need!!!
CImage img = createCImage(imgBits, width, height, Bpp);

// Test the image
BYTE* data = img.GetBits();  // data should now have the same data as imgBits
```

All implementations of `createCImage()` so far have ended up with `data` pointing to an empty (zero filled) array.

Comment: Looks like you need to fill in a BITMAPINFO structure for your imgBits, instantiate a CImage, call Create() to create an empty bitmap of the correct size, GetDC() to get your CImage's DC and then use ::SetDIBitsToDevice() to draw your imgBits to your CImage.

Comment: @tinman: Thanks, it looks like this is the way to go. I'm sure I've been down this route before, but gave up because I don't think I got the header right. I'll give it another go...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I managed to solve it in the end with your help. It mainly involved @tinman and @Roel's suggestion to use `SetDIBitsToDevice()`, but it involved a bit of extra bit-twiddling and memory management, so I thought I'd share my end-point here.

In the code below, I assume that `width`, `height` and `Bpp` (**Bytes** per pixel) are set, and that `data` is a pointer to the array of RGB pixel values.

```
// Create the header info
bmInfohdr.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bmInfohdr.biWidth = width;
bmInfohdr.biHeight = -height;
bmInfohdr.biPlanes = 1;
bmInfohdr.biBitCount = Bpp*8;
bmInfohdr.biCompression = BI_RGB;
bmInfohdr.biSizeImage = width*height*Bpp;
bmInfohdr.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
bmInfohdr.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
bmInfohdr.biClrUsed = 0;
bmInfohdr.biClrImportant = 0;

BITMAPINFO bmInfo;
bmInfo.bmiHeader = bmInfohdr;
bmInfo.bmiColors[0].rgbBlue=255;

// Allocate some memory and some pointers
unsigned char * p24Img = new unsigned char[width*height*3];
BYTE *pTemp,*ptr;
pTemp=(BYTE*)data;
ptr=p24Img;

// Convert image from RGB to BGR
for (DWORD index = 0; index < width*height ; index++)
{
    unsigned char r = *(pTemp++);
    unsigned char g = *(pTemp++);
    unsigned char b = *(pTemp++);   

    *(ptr++) = b;
    *(ptr++) = g;
    *(ptr++) = r;
}

// Create the CImage
CImage im;
im.Create(width, height, 24, NULL);

HDC dc = im.GetDC();
SetDIBitsToDevice(dc, 0,0,width,height,0,0, 0, height, p24Img, &bmInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
im.ReleaseDC();

delete[] p24Img;
```

Comment: Are you sure this works for images of various sizes? I looked it up, MSDN indeed says "The scan lines must be aligned on a DWORD except for RLE-compressed bitmaps." I dug out some code I once wrote that did roughly something like this, I malloc'ed more memory than you do:

    int rowlength = 4 * ((nCols * 24 + 31) / 32);
    BYTE* pBits = (BYTE*)malloc(rowlength * nRows);

and then filled the values in that array like this:

    pBits[(bitmap_r * rowlength) + bitmap_c] = GetBValue(color);

(this set the color components one by one, bitmap_c iterated over (3 * n_cols))

Comment: Man these comments suck, no code formatting, can't even put in a newline :(

Comment: Hmm, thats a good point. I'm not sure actually, all of my image frames are 640x480, so I don't have a problem. But you're right, other sizes may cause problems.

Comment: Oh I see, yes when your images are always screen resolutions, you should be good - they're (currently) always multiples of 4.

Comment: im.Detach() assert failed m_hBitmap != 0

Answer (score 1):

`CImage` supports DIBs quite neatly and has a `SetPixel()` method so you could presumably do something like this (uncompiled, untested code ahead!):

```
CImage img;
img.Create(width, height, 24 /* bpp */, 0 /* No alpha channel */);

int nPixel = 0;
for(int row = 0; row < height; row++)
{
    for(int col = 0; col < width; col++)
    {
        BYTE r = imgBits[nPixel++];
        BYTE g = imgBits[nPixel++];
        BYTE b = imgBits[nPixel++];
        img.SetPixel(row, col, RGB(r, g, b));
    }
}
```

Maybe not the most efficient method but I should think it is the simplest approach.

Comment: @ATT: Thanks, this will certainly work, but I was after something a lot more efficient than this, as I'm using it on a live video feed @25 fps

Comment: @ltn100 -- fair enough, if speed is an issue you will need to do something smarter. I think you can still create the CImage the same way, then use GetBits() to get a pointer to the DIB byte array, and copy your image bytes in to modify the CImage on the fly. I _think_ (off the top of my head) that DIBSections expect BGR not RGB so you may need to do some manipulation of the bytes unfortunately.

Comment: I used this approach originally once (when I wrote my first graphics/GDI project :) ) and the SetPixel() approach was between 100 and 250 times slower than using a raw byte data buffer, depending one some variables like video card etc.

Comment: @Roel - I am not at all surprised, I've seen similar results in the past. It gets something going quickly but is only viable for final code if performance is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use memcpy to copy the data, then SetDIBits or SetDIBitsToDevice depending on what you need to do. Take care though, the scanlines of the raw image data are aligned on 4-byte boundaries (IIRC, it's been a few years since I did this) so the data you get back from GetDIBits will never be exactly the same as the original data (well it might, depending on the image size).

So most likely you will need to memcpy scanline by scanline.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler solution. You can use GetPixelAddress(...) instead of all this BITMAPHEADERINFO and SedDIBitsToDevice. Another problem I have solved was with 8-bit images, which need to have the color table defined.

```
CImage outImage;
outImage.Create(width, height, channelCount * 8);

int lineSize = width * channelCount;
if (channelCount == 1)
{
    // Define the color table
    RGBQUAD* tab = new RGBQUAD[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    {
        tab[i].rgbRed = i;
        tab[i].rgbGreen = i;
        tab[i].rgbBlue = i;
        tab[i].rgbReserved = 0;
    }
    outImage.SetColorTable(0, 256, tab);
    delete[] tab;
}

// Copy pixel values
// Warining: does not convert from RGB to BGR
for ( int i = 0; i < height; i++ )
{
    void*       dst = outImage.GetPixelAddress(0, i);
    const void* src = /* put the pointer to the i'th source row here */;
    memcpy(dst, src, lineSize);
}
```