# OpenCV Mat of cropped images do not correctly display on MFC View

Tags: c++, mfc, opencv

I am using following routines to display OpenCV Mat on MFC View. And it's working well for uncropped images. But for pre-cropped images, it shows blank or weird images like the ones below:

First one is displayed on usual image software such as MS Paint and the second is on my MFC view. Difficult is that uncropped image files are displaying just fine. I am not sure this is fault of SetDIBitsToDevice or OpenCV. But clearly SetDIBitsToDevice loses constant number of bytes in each row. Anybody has any idea to fix this problem?

[image: Correct] [image: Displayed]

```
cv::Mat m_cvImage;
static int Bpp(cv::Mat img) { return 8 * img.channels(); } 


void COpenCVTestView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
COpenCVTestDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
if (!pDoc)
    return;
if(pDoc->m_cvImage.empty()) return;
// TODO: add draw code for native data here
int height=pDoc->m_cvImage.rows;
int width=pDoc->m_cvImage.cols;
uchar buffer[sizeof( BITMAPINFOHEADER ) + 1024]; 
BITMAPINFO* bmi = (BITMAPINFO* )buffer; 
FillBitmapInfo(bmi,width,height,Bpp(pDoc->m_cvImage),0);
SetDIBitsToDevice(pDC->GetSafeHdc(), 0, 0, width,
    height, 0, 0, 0, height, pDoc->m_cvImage.data, bmi,
    DIB_RGB_COLORS);
}


void COpenCVTestView::FillBitmapInfo(BITMAPINFO* bmi, int width, int height, int bpp, int origin) 
{ 
assert(bmi && width >= 0 && height >= 0 && (bpp == 8 || bpp == 24 || bpp == 32)); 

BITMAPINFOHEADER* bmih = &(bmi->bmiHeader); 

memset(bmih, 0, sizeof(*bmih)); 
bmih->biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER); 
bmih->biWidth = width; 
bmih->biHeight = origin ? abs(height) : -abs(height); 
bmih->biPlanes = 1; 
bmih->biBitCount = (unsigned short)bpp; 
bmih->biCompression = BI_RGB; 

if (bpp == 8) 
{ 
    RGBQUAD* palette = bmi->bmiColors; 

            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) 
    { 
        palette[i].rgbBlue = palette[i].rgbGreen = palette[i].rgbRed = (BYTE)i; 
        palette[i].rgbReserved = 0; 
    } 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Roel says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8587720/5987), the bitmap data needs to be DWORD aligned. This is an incomplete description of the problem however; *each row* of the data needs to start on a DWORD boundary. Typically you insert 0 to 3 bytes of padding at the end of each row to ensure this.

If it is inconvenient or impossible to pad the rows, simply make sure the width of the image is evenly divisible by 4.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I was totally confused by what Roel said about DWORD aligned. Now I understand number of columns x number of channels should be a multiple of 4

Answer (score 3):

I didn't investigate your example in detail, but be aware that the data you pass to SetDIBitsToDevice needs to be aligned on DWORD boundaries (IIRC). Maybe your 90% cases where it works are of the same size and things are accidentally correct, and when you rotate the alignment switches.

I would expect though that in this case you wouldn't see no output, but maybe the GDI driver detects the wrong alignment and doesn't do any blitting at all. Sounds reasonable.

I think I posted an example of a function that correctly aligns on DWORD boundaries for use with SetDIBitsToDevice to SO earlier, search for my posts for a code example.

Comment: One thing for sure 90% cases are not of the same size. It works from very small images to 8MB images. Secondly, I didn't rotate the image. It was already rotated when I got it. Also I found [related answer you mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6759701/931170) but I don't see any difference from my code. Your answer however made me think more about my question and I will update the question soon. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I reread the question and yes it's a bit different than I thought - you're using the bitmap data straight out of the OpenCV data you have (my post on that link is about how the data that is passed to the SetDIBitsToDevice functions is malloc'ed and filled). Still, the data you use needs to be DWORD-aligned, I'd be surprised if OpenCV would do that for you. As to the rotation, I'm not sure - I thought you meant that the data you got was 'pre-rotated' so to say, so just the n rows and n cols swapped, but maybe there is something else going on in the OpenCV object.

Comment: I think you are right. When I made the image to single-channel gray-level, image displays in a weird way - Please see my answer for the picture. So I would like to know how I can DWORD-align data as you suggested?

Comment: You'd have to malloc a new block of memory (as in the comment in the thread you linked to above, i.e. with extra space for the padding of rows) and then copy over your data from the OpenCV data into your own memory. Then pass your own memory block to SetDIBitsToDevice.

Comment: Thanks! I've already figured it out thanks to Mark's answer above. Wished MSDN be friendly like your explanation.