# How can I find reason of the error when SetDIBitsToDevice returns error code (0)

Tags: c++, windows

**Background:** I am using OpenCV2 library in my MFC application and SetDIBitsToDevice to display each image. My problem is that following code works with 90% of image files but does not work with certain rotated images for the reason I don't know. [Whole description of the issue is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546815/some-opencv-mat-of-rotated-images-do-not-display-on-mfc-view)

So I need to find out why the function is returning 0 error code for the images and what error I am getting from the function.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162974%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> If zero scan lines are set (such as when dwHeight is 0) or the
>   function fails, the function returns zero.

So if the function returns zero, how can I find details of the error?

**UPDATE:** I tried to use GetLastError() as following. But actually message was "Operation completed successfully" that is not true, of course. I would appreciate any hint or advice to attack this issue.

```
BITMAPINFO* bmi = (BITMAPINFO* )buffer; 
FillBitmapInfo(bmi,width,height,Bpp(pDoc->m_cvImage),0);
int result = SetDIBitsToDevice(pDC->GetSafeHdc(), 100, 100, width,
    height, 0, 0, 0, height, pDoc->m_cvImage.data, bmi,
    DIB_RGB_COLORS);
if(result==0) {
    DWORD error = GetLastError();
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    FormatMessage( 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        error,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), // Default language
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0,
        NULL 
    );
    CString text;
    // Process any inserts in lpMsgBuf.
    text= (LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf;
    // Free the buffer.
    LocalFree( lpMsgBuf );      
    int nResult = AfxMessageBox(text, MB_OK);

}
```

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. Funny thing is when I translated the value from the function to the string message using FormatMessage, I got "The operation completed successfully" which is not true.

Comment: A common mistake is to call some other winapi function that gets the error code reset.  Call it immediately and store the return value in a local variable.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think I am doing that though. According to google search, I think it's a no-description problem with Bitmap functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most GDI functions do not use `GetLastError()` (some do, such as `BitBlt()`), and GDI does not define its own error codes other than `0` and `GDI_ERROR`.  If a failure occurs, there is usually no way to determine what the actual error is. you just have to review your code with a fine tooth comb looking for logic mistakes.

Since you are having issues with rotated images, I would start by looking at them first.  They probably do not have the same dimensions that you are expecting, so they do not match the parameters you are passing to `SetDIBitsToDevice()`.

Comment: When I make the image to gray-level, then it's displayed in a strange way. I suspect rows and columns messed but even I exchanged width and height, it does not display original image at all. Here is [full description of the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546815/some-opencv-mat-of-rotated-images-do-not-display-on-mfc-view) in case you are interested.

Answer (score 2):

If you are meant to call GetLastError when an API fails, this will be documented. Since the documentation makes no mention of GetLastError it appears that there is no further information provided in event of a failure beyond the information encoded in the return value.

> If the function succeeds, the return value is the number of
>   scan lines set.
>
> If zero scan lines are set (such as when dwHeight is 0) or the function fails, the function returns zero.
>
> If the driver cannot support the JPEG or PNG file image passed to SetDIBitsToDevice, the function will fail and return GDI_ ERROR. If failure does occur, the application must fall back on its own JPEG or PNG support to decompress the image into a bitmap, and then pass the bitmap to SetDIBitsToDevice.

I am afraid it looks like you are pretty much on your own here.

Comment: Yeah it appears that way. Can you suggest any way to attack this issue?

Comment: I think I'd attack this by searching for something common about the images that fail

Comment: My copy of the MSDN library says it does.  We've had this discussion before, not sure what's going on.

Comment: @hans I looked here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162974(v=vs.85).aspx where did you look?

Comment: In my own copy, installed on my machine back when I installed VS.  I'm not much of a fan of the web interface, too slow.  It is dated of course.

Comment: When I make the image to gray-level, then it's displayed in a strange way. I suspect rows and columns messed but even I exchanged width and height, it does not display original image at all. Here is [full description of the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546815/some-opencv-mat-of-rotated-images-do-not-display-on-mfc-view) in case you are interested.