# BYTE[] to CImage (C++)

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm struggling at the moment and hope that someone can help me.

I'm getting an Image out of a SQL-Database andt store it to a BYTE[].
Now I have to convert it to a CImage to show it in my program.

I would be happy for any help.

Heres my Code:

```
SQLLEN    cbData;
CImage    image;
BYTE  testByte[arrSize];

try
{
    m_Rc = ExecuteDirect(SQLStmt_Select, "SELECT ImgDat FROM ImgMap", "ImgTyp = 'AtlStm.AtlImg'", Empty_String, Empty_String, Empty_String, Empty_String);
    m_RcFetch = SQLFetch(m_Hstmt);      
    m_Rc = SQLGetData(m_Hstmt, 1, SQL_C_BINARY, &testByte, arrSize, &cbData);
}
// store testByte in image
```

In C# I just wrote the Byte[] to a MemoryStream and used this to create an Image. But in C++ I have absolutely no idea.

My C# Code:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection(strCn);
        cn.Open();

        OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(sqlCommand, cn);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds, "ImgMap");
        int c = ds.Tables["ImgMap"].Rows.Count;

        if (c > 0)
        {
            Byte[] byteBLOBData = new Byte[0];
            byteBLOBData = (Byte[])(ds.Tables["ImgMap"].Rows[c - 1]["ImgDat"]);
            MemoryStream stmBLOBData = new MemoryStream(byteBLOBData);
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stmBLOBData);
        }
        cn.Close();
```

**Edit:**
this is my current code, it works but my control stays empty.

```
BOOL DBStatement::GetSqlData_Image(CWnd* parent, CImage image, CStatic* dc)
{
SQLLEN    cbData;
BYTE  testByte[2048];

int width  = 312;
int height = 159;
void* bits;

try
{
    m_Rc = ExecuteDirect(SQLStmt_Select, "SELECT ImgDat FROM ImgMap", "ImgTyp = 'AtlStm.AtlImg'", Empty_String, Empty_String, Empty_String, Empty_String);
    m_RcFetch = SQLFetch(m_Hstmt);      
    m_Rc = SQLGetData(m_Hstmt, 1, SQL_C_BINARY, &testByte, 2048, &cbData);

    BITMAPFILEHEADER* bmfh;
    bmfh = (BITMAPFILEHEADER*)testByte;

    BITMAPINFOHEADER* bmih;
    bmih = (BITMAPINFOHEADER*)(testByte + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
    BITMAPINFO* bmi;
    bmi = (BITMAPINFO*)bmih;

    bits = (void*)(testByte + bmfh->bfOffBits);


    CDC *screenDC = AfxGetMainWnd()->GetDC();
    CDC mDC;
    mDC.CreateCompatibleDC(screenDC);
    CBitmap b;
    b.CreateCompatibleBitmap(screenDC, 300, 150);

    CBitmap *pob = mDC.SelectObject(&b);
    mDC.SetStretchBltMode(HALFTONE);
    CRect rectDest(0, 0, width, height);
    image.StretchBlt(mDC.m_hDC, rectDest);
    mDC.SelectObject(pob);

    HBITMAP hbmp = CreateDIBitmap(mDC.m_hDC, bmih, CBM_INIT, bits, bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    b.Attach(hbmp);

    dc->SetBitmap((HBITMAP)b.Detach());
}
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691292/create-cimage-from-byte-array and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993518/arraybyte-to-hbitmap-or-cbitmap

Comment: Call the overload of `CImage::Load` that allows you to load an image from an `IStream`. That should be the same thing as you're doing in C#.

Comment: @Cody Gray. Thanks, but how do I write my BYTE[] to an IStream? I never worked with it before :)

Comment: *"how do I write my BYTE[] to an IStream?"* - [SHCreateMemStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773831.aspx).

Comment: Did you try `CImage::SetPixel`? BTW, try first to load an image from disk with `CImage::Load` and enter iniside the MFC classes in the debugger to see what is happening.